# how to create an oscilloscope in javafx?

Tags: javafx

it's the first time that I use javafx. I am creating a program that took an audio file, analyzing their characteristics (forming, frequency, intensity ...). Right now my goal is to play the audio files I loaded (and this is not a problem) and to show during its run an oscilloscope.

So I would create a simple oscilloscope  but I am not clear how to do? any suggestions? how could I start?

I had a look at this link, but I can not apply it because it is in JPanel

http://codeidol.com/java/swing/Audio/Build-an-Audio-Waveform-Display/

you could tell me some other link to help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow!What libraries are you using to play the audio?What type of audio you want to support?Your question is really hard to be answered as one here.For frequency analysis you have to use FFT(Fast Fourier Transform) . Let us know the info above for further details :)

Comment: hello, for audio files I used javafx.scene.media. the supported file types are .mp3 and .wav.
I created a media player window and in it I would like to see an oscillogram. for the moment I do not care extrapolate values ​​(forming, intensity ...) I would try to display a simple oscillogram of the loaded sound. it can be done?

Comment: Yes.Although i am doing these things with custom algorithms and libraries from `javazoom.net` . First do some search on youtube for javafx oscilloscope ready programs , you might find some and then i  think of creating some videos to show how it can be done using FFT . It's a big topic and it is expected to have good knowledge of Java , Audio internally and mathematics. Finally i want to mention that JavaFX has already builded libraries to create a visualizer  for audio and video so do a better research  :)

Comment: thanks, I'm still a student you do not have much command of language, I manage and I put effort. I would still try to realize the oscillograme, if we were to not succeed patience, but I want to try. Would you be so kind to postarmi some links useful for this purpose? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this site:
Java Program to create a PNG waveform for an audio file

[Java Program to create a PNG waveform for an audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017283/java-program-to-create-a-png-waveform-for-an-audio-file)

See there!